# Bigcommerce Mailchimp integration creates users without subscribtion status

Tags: mailchimp, bigcommerce

Good morning, i installed mailchimp app into my bigcommerce store, i can now see the new bigcommerce customer appera in mymailchimp list when they sign up in bigcommerce. The problem is that the "Email marketing" status is not "Sbuscribed" but it is blank, and i cannot use theese contacts to send emails.
I create the bigcommerce users using API and not the template signup form, and the "accepts_marketing" flat is false by default and it is readonly. 
How can i solve this problem? i need the users as Subscribed in my mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

The "accepts_marketing" flag on the customer record indicates whether the customer has opted in to receive abandoned cart recovery and review emails--it's not used to track marketing newsletter preferences. Newsletter subscriptions fall under the Subscribers resource:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/customer-subscribers/subscribers-api/subscribers/createsubscriber

The Mailchimp app will be listening for a POST to the /customers/subscribers resource to create a new newsletter subscriber, so if you're creating users programmatically, you'll need to create the subscriber separately from the customer record.